# Including XML library in Qt

Tags: xml, qt, include

I have issues including a couple of libaries in Qt:

```
#include <QXmlStreamWriter>
```

These are located at top of my class, Qt Core are included into the Pro file (I'm using Qt creator), just a complete normal inclusion I have done hundred of times before (including this).

This town even though I declare nothing from QXmlStreamWriter in my class the compiler throws this error when I compile it:
(Shortened down the full path)

```
Qt\4.8.1\mingw\include\QtCore\qxmlstream.h:471: error: 'void QXmlStreamWriter::writeStartElement(const QString&, const QString&)' cannot be overloaded
```

The error is at the "include" line itself. There is absolutely nothing in the rest of the class that does anything with it at the moment.

This is the class it is included in:

```
#include "charactersheetlayout.h"
#include "ui_charactersheetlayout.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QXmlStreamWriter> //This is where the compiler complains. 

characterSheetLayout::characterSheetLayout(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::characterSheetLayout)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
//Just checking that a folder exists, nothing important.
    if(!QDir("csTemplates").exists())
    {
        this->createDefaultTemplate();
    }
}
```

The header file does not have anything that is related to QXmlStreamWriter.

Appreciate any help I get :-)

Edit:
Header file on request, note that every function and variable does actually not contain any code at the moment.

```
#ifndef CHARACTERSHEETLAYOUT_H
#define CHARACTERSHEETLAYOUT_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class characterSheetLayout;
}

class characterSheetLayout : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit characterSheetLayout(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~characterSheetLayout();
    int validateSheet();
    void promptError(QString error);
    void standard3_5();

private:
    Ui::characterSheetLayout *ui;
    void createDefaultTemplate();
};

#endif // CHARACTERSHEETLAYOUT_H
```

Pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += webkit
QT       += network

TARGET = dndManager
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += release

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    startscreen.cpp \
    createadventure.cpp \
    charactersheetlayout.cpp \
    gameui.cpp \
    character.cpp \
    characterscreen.cpp \
    gamescreen.cpp \
    settings.cpp \
    wikidisplay.cpp \
    admincharacterscreen.cpp \
    server.cpp \
    participant.cpp \
    connectionmanager.cpp \
    client.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    startscreen.h \
    createadventure.h \
    charactersheetlayout.h \
    gameui.h \
    character.h \
    characterscreen.h \
    gamescreen.h \
    settings.h \
    wikidisplay.h \
    admincharacterscreen.h \
    server.h \
    participant.h \
    connectionmanager.h \
    client.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui \
    startscreen.ui \
    createadventure.ui \
    charactersheetlayout.ui \
    gameui.ui \
    characterscreen.ui \
    gamescreen.ui \
    settings.ui \
    wikidisplay.ui \
    admincharacterscreen.ui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **XML module** in the `.pro` file :

```
QT += xml
```